# What software is used to draw undirected graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, math-software

I need to make a nicer-looking version of this image:

[image: Undirected graph with crappy loop]

Is there some program that generates these graphs? Or are they done by hand in something like Visio?

(I'm on Mac OS X, and I have access to Windows if needed)

Comment: I use gastex or MetaPost.

Comment: See also [this post on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11049/is-there-a-way-to-draw-a-graph-vertices-edges-in-latex-on-this-website).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

Comment: I quickly figured out the DOT language and made the graph as I wanted it. Thanks!

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, would it be possible for you to include an example of the above graph drawn by Graphviz?

Answer (score 5):

If you use $\LaTeX$, tikz is very nice for making graphs (I use it all the time to make commutative diagrams).

Otherwise one could use pretty much any vector graphics program, for example the free (as in freedom and in beer) [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/).

There's also [dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia/), though it is more for UML-like diagrams.

Answer (score 3):

[Sage](http://www.sagenb.org/) can generate graphs.  It's like Mathematica/Maple but it's open source and free.

Answer (score 3):

The [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/) library for [R](http://www.r-project.org/) allows you to plot graphs.  Combined with [tikzDevice](http://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=440), it can also produce LaTeX output of the plots.

Here's an example:

[image: The OP's graph]

The graph itself was produced using the R code

```
g <- graph.empty() + vertices(letters[1:3])
g <- add.edges(g,c(1,2,2,3,3,1,2,2))
g <- as.undirected(g)
```

and was plotted to a LaTeX file using the R code

```
tikz("~/Dropbox/Thesis/Thoughts/temp.tex",standAlone=FALSE,width=4,height=4)
plot(g,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold,vertex.size=30,edge.width=3,edge.color="black")
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since no one else has mentioned it yet, [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html), a free diagram/graph editor.

Comment: Highly recommend this one. I used it to create diagrams for my thesis and in many other occasions.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/gliffy/#) to be a great method of doing this, and it has the advantage of being totally web based--nothing to install or screw up across operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Try Gephi is a open source mac for graphs....http://gephi.org

Answer (score 1):

**Simple, online, free**

If graph layout does not matter you can use Wolfram Alpha

```
Graph 1->2, 1->3, 2->3, 2->2
```

[image]
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Graph+1-%3E2,+1-%3E3,+2-%3E3,+2-%3E2

Answer (score 0):

Just adding one other option. [TikZiT](http://tikzit.sourceforge.net/) seems to bee a multi-platform GUI tool that can generate TikZ code (for inclusion in LaTeX documents). Together with [QtikZ/Ktikz](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language/) this can be used to quickly produce pdf and/or png versions of a graph.